# Is there a way to find the TTL start value of the pinged server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line, ping

For example, if I ping `www.google.com` I get `TTL=114`, is there a way for me to find what was the initial TLL value for `www.google.com`

Comment: Are you sure about that? My TTL value is 128, how do I get TTL=240 when I'm pinging some sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TTL time has to do with traversing from point A to point B on the internet.
No one *has* a TTL, and the route taken between the points may vary,
even on each ping (although rarely).

Read about
[ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)),
where TTL is defined as the number of network hops that the probe traversed.

However, the little twist here is that the TTL number that you see is set
to its initial value by the *destination device*, then is decremented by one
for each hop that the return has taken.

The problem is that each device
or operating system may have a different initial value.

Here an old table the someone has compiled:
[Initial TTL values](https://web.archive.org/web/20100129075203/http://members.cox.net/%7Endav1/self_published/TTL_values.html).
The TTL value that you receive may actually give you a hint about the
responding device and/or OS.

Comment: My question is probably worded a bit wrong, inital TTL value is what I'm looking for, is there a way to get the initial TTL value of a server?

Comment: and I understand that Inital TTL value varies by OS but is there way to know for sure what was the inital value of the pinged server?

Comment: You could ping it from a nearby computer. Or use both ping and `tracert/traceroute` and add the two values. That will give you some estimate. There aren't that many values used, as you can see in the old link I gave above for Initial TTL values.

Comment: Yeah, the problem appeared cause I had to figure out which OS is used on a remote computer by it's inital ttl which was 255 and 255 matches multiple OS.